# How new object working in the latest version of PHP

Tags: php, type-hinting, php-7.2, static-typing

As per the PHP 7.2 documentation

> A new type, object, has been introduced that can be used for (contravariant) parameter typing and (covariant) return typing of any objects.

And the following example has been given

```
<?php

function test(object $obj) : object
{
   return new SplQueue();
}

test(new StdClass());
```

Can someone elaborate what is meant by contravariant parameter and covariant return type and how this new object work

Answer (score -1):

`object` in both places in your code can return generic object i.e an instance of any type. (as shown in your example)

Else it would need to be:

```
<?php

function test(StdClass $obj) : SplQueue
{
   return new SplQueue();
}

test(new StdClass());
```